# Class doesn't recognize a method in Java

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I'm having several problems with the following code:

```
private ArrayList<TemperatureSensor> sensors = new ArrayList<TemperatureSensor>();

//[...]

private double getAverageTemperature() {
    double addition = 0;
    for(TemperatureSensor sensor : this.sensors)
        addition += sensor.getTemperature();
        return addition / this.sensors.size();
    }
}
```

The method getTemperature is in the class TemperatureSensor, and it's defined as this:

```
public int getTemperature() {
    // random number [5,40]
    return new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt(36)+5;
}
```

In the getAverageTemperature() method I'm getting an error saying that "The method getTemperature() is undefined for the type TemperatureSensor"

Also, how do I call a specific method that two classes have, and their objects are stored in an ArrayList, from an abstract class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to avoid tabs in code. It's a PITA

Comment: Should compile. But you seem to have a logic error as well. I think you want to move the line `return addition / this.sensors.size()` down below the closing brace of the for-loop.

Comment: Code looks fine. Whats really annoying you? Can you put the full code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean and compile you code once again as code looks fine. For your second question, find example below

```
public abstract class A {


    public abstract void method();

}

public class B extends A{
    public  void method(){
        //code
    }
}

public class C extends A {
    public  void method(){
        //code
    }
}

public class Main{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<A> obj=new ArrayList<A>();
        obj.add(new B());
        obj.add(new C());
        for (A a : obj) {
            a.method(); // it will call respective method of B and C class
        } 
    }        

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code looks ok. Does everything compile? Is everything freshly compiled? From what you describe I'd assume there is an old version of the class on your classpath that does not yet have that method.